# Do not backtrack over single argument

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate that, given a list, creates a partition for this list (i.e it splits into two parts). This predicate can thus generate multiple solutions.

For each part of the partition, I will generate all the possible permutations.

And then for these permutations I will do some sort of test.

Suppose the following:

```
:- generatePartition(List, A, B),
   permutation(A,Perm1),
   permutation(B, Perm2),
   test(Perm1),
   test(Perm2).
```

The point here is, that if the test succeeds for `Perm1`, this is the only `Perm1` I need.

If next, the test fails for `Perm2`, I want to try every possible permutation for `Perm2`. If they all fail I immediatly want a new partition. I do not want to generate a different permutation for `A`.

I tried the following (add some sort of scope to the cut):

```
:- generatePartition(List, A, B),
   permutation(A,Perm1),
   permutation(B, Perm2),
   (
       test(Perm1),!
   ),
   test(Perm2).
```

Is there any possible solution to this? I broke my brain on this one today :)

Comment: Put `once/1` around the goal. That is `once(permutation(A,Perm1))`

Comment: Also, `once(G)` is the same as `(G -> true ; fail)`.

Comment: True, but `once/1` is semantically much more clear.

Comment: @WillNess: No, not the same. But in this case here, yes, it is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with IF-THEN construct:

```
:- generatePartition(List, A, B),
   (   permutation(A,Perm1),
       test(Perm1)             % just one Perm1 for which test succeeds
   ->
       permutation(B, Perm2),
       test(Perm2)             % all the Perm2 such that test succeeds
   ).
```

In general, you can create scope by creating an auxiliary named predicate and using it instead of a block of code. Then you can use cut inside that auxiliary predicate.

But there's already a predicate `once/1`, as pointed out by [user:false] in the comments:

```
:- generatePartition(List, A, B),
   once( (permutation(A,Perm1), test(Perm1)) ),
   permutation(B, Perm2),
   test(Perm2).
```

Comment: The `once` dit the trick allright! :) Thank you very much @false and @Will Ness. The program is acting as wanted now.